# How to draw moving axis table

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to draw an axis table (x-y) in WPF from code-behind; and I want to give it drag and drop option which can see more of the axis table.
I had created static axis but I don't know how to create a dynamic one?
Can anybody help me with this stuff ?
Thanks.

```
            for (int i = 10; i < 400; i+=10)
        {
            Line a = new Line();
            a.X1 = 0;
            a.Y1 = i;
            a.X2 = canGraph.Width;
            a.Y2 = a.Y1;
            a.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
            a.StrokeThickness = 0.5;
            canGraph.Children.Add(a);

            Line b = new Line();
            b.X1 = i;
            b.Y1 = 0;
            b.X2 = i;
            b.Y2 = canGraph.Height;
            b.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
            b.StrokeThickness = 0.5;
            canGraph.Children.Add(b);
            if (i % 50 == 0)
            {
                a.StrokeThickness = 1;
                b.StrokeThickness = 1;
            }

            if (i == 200)
            {
                a.StrokeThickness = 2;
                b.StrokeThickness = 2;
            }



        }
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have done so far?

Comment: @GauravMathur Here you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started. Add event handler(s) to your main axis and `canGraph` -

```
    ...
    if (i == 200)
    {
       a.StrokeThickness = 2;
       b.StrokeThickness = 2;

       a.MouseLeftButtonDown += A_MouseLeftButtonDown;
    }
}
canGraph.MouseLeftButtonUp += CanGraph_MouseLeftButtonUp;
canGraph.MouseMove += CanGraph_MouseMove;
```

Add following methods -

```
    Line _selectedAxis = null;

    private void CanGraph_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_selectedAxis != null)
        {
            var line = _selectedAxis;
            var pos = e.GetPosition(line);
            textBlock.Text = $"({pos.X}, {pos.Y})";
            line.Y1 = pos.Y;
            line.Y2 = pos.Y;
        }
    }

    private void CanGraph_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _selectedAxis = null;
    }

    private void A_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var line = sender as Line;
        _selectedAxis = line;
    }
```

Now hold you main horizontal axis and drag it.

You can do the same for vertical axis as well.

**For Zooming**

Initialize `canGraph.RenderTransform` with `ScaleTransform` and subscribe to `MouseWheel` event. Note `RenderTransformOrigin` is set to (0.5, 0.5) to zoom from center instead of top left (default) -

```
canGraph.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
canGraph.RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform();
canGraph.MouseWheel += CanGraph_MouseWheel;
```

And the function -

```
private void CanGraph_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var transform = canGraph.RenderTransform as ScaleTransform;
    var factor = transform.ScaleX;
    factor += (e.Delta > 0 ? 1 : (factor == 1 ? 0 : -1));
    transform.ScaleX = factor;
    transform.ScaleY = factor;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, would you help me on zooming in and out by mouse scrolling ?

Comment: Updated my answer for zoom using Mouse Wheel. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have added `Line` type object to draw axes, then gave it to window content.
Then just add events, like `MouseLeftButtonDown` event, or `MouseMove` event.Add appropriate methods.
Change your object positions on `MouseMove` event, like:
(For a certain line)

```
private void MouseMoveMethod(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = sender as Line;

            obj.X1 = e.GetPosition(this).X; //Line start x coordinate
            obj.Y1 = e.GetPosition(this).Y; //Line start y coordinate
            ...
        }
```